# passing `apify_api_token` as a named parameter

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, apify

I am new to python, I am trying to pass the API key to apifywrapper here in the notebook. I am getting this error:

> ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in <cell line: 9>()
> 7 api_token = userdata.get("apify")
> 8
> ----> 9 apify = ApifyWrapper(apify_api_token=api_token)
> 10 # Call the Actor to obtain text from the crawled webpages
> 11 loader = apify.call_actor(
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/main.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
> in pydantic.main.BaseModel.**init**()
>
> ValidationError: 1 validation error for ApifyWrapper
> **root**   Did not find apify_api_token, please add an environment variable `APIFY_API_TOKEN` which contains it, or pass
> `apify_api_token` as a named parameter. (type=value_error)

```
!pip install apify apify-client 
from langchain.docstore.document import Document
from langchain.indexes import VectorstoreIndexCreator
from langchain.utilities import ApifyWrapper
import apify

api_token = userdata.get("apify")
apify = ApifyWrapper(apify_api_token=api_token)
# Call the Actor to obtain text from the crawled webpages
loader = apify.call_actor(
    actor_id="apify/website-content-crawler",
    run_input={"startUrls": [{"url": "https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/chat/"}]},
    dataset_mapping_function=lambda item: Document(
        page_content=item["text"] or "", metadata={"source": item["url"]}
    ),
)
```

Can explain to me what am I doing wrong and how can I fix this problem?
Ty

Answer (score 0):

The error "ValidationError: Did not find apify_api_token, please add an environment variable APIFY_API_TOKEN which contains it, or pass apify_api_token as a named parameter" is occurring because the APIFY_API_TOKEN environment variable is missing. To fix this, you can either set the APIFY_API_TOKEN environment variable or pass apify_api_token as a named parameter when creating an instance of the ApifyWrapper class.
Here's how you can set the environment variable in Python:

```
import os
os.environ["APIFY_API_TOKEN"] = "[your API token]"
apify = ApifyWrapper( )
```